# Problems on Page Load ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, data-binding, datasource

When you go to this page http://tuckertrans.com/ComputerInventory.aspx my navbar displays vertical until the grid loads. My grid also takes 2-3 seconds to load. Im just grabbing the list from the database, assigning that list to the grid's datasource, and finally binding the data. Whats taking so long for the page to load? This causes my navbar orientation to be wrong until it loads. Any way to speed this up?

```
Dim li As List(Of ComputerInfo) = Process.Get_Computers() 
Me.gvComputers.DataSource = li 
Me.gvComputers.EditIndex = -1 
Me.gvComputers.DataBind()
```

Comment: I guess it because you got a lot of data in your sql database.

Comment: I don't know, never used that much.. You should try get it on localhost server and watch the loading there, if it works fine then your host is might be the problem.

Comment: I don't understand tho because before I put my list into the grid's datasource it has all the rows in the list. heres a sample of my code.

Comment: Dim li As List(Of ComputerInfo) = Process.Get_Computers()
        Me.gvComputers.DataSource = li
        Me.gvComputers.EditIndex = -1
        Me.gvComputers.DataBind()
<code>
Get_Computers() is where im getting the 230 rows from the database so I don't understand how its taking that long to bind because they are already loaded in the list before binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my navbar displays vertical until the grid loads

Client browser receives CSS files later than ComputerInventory.aspx. It is normal in web page.

However, in your case, your web page has too many data. As the result, it makes every thing slow.

Ideally, you want to use Pagination with Ajax. In addition, you only want to retrieve data that you want to display. *For example, retrieving 10 rows from database using skip and take.*

[image]

Comment: I really don't want to use pagination because I need the users to be to look through the list as fast as possible. instead of having to page over. Any other ways around this or how can I display a loading spinner while it loads? Im pretty new to this so any code on how to do that would be great!

Comment: Normally, we provide Search/Filter feature (in addition to pagination with Ajax) to a user if there are too many records. However, it is up to you. The worst case you can display **Loading icon** while the page is loading. There are too many discussions and articles about that loading image in SO and Google.